# Get error after update modules to view Map

Tags: debugging

After I updated modules, I get the below error, but everything seems to be working fine:

> Out of a total of 40 result rows in view Map List Business (Block Maps
>   ), 1 rows did not have their field_coordinates set and therefore could
>   not be shown on the map. The first row that could not be located was
>   row #1. You can improve execution efficiency by using the Views UI to
>   add an "is not empty" filter for field_coordinates.

What should I do about it?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the error you might want to follow what it says should be done: fix the entity with an empty field_coordinates and/or add a filter in the view.

Comment: The more information you can give the better. For example: Which modules did you update? On which pages and under which circumstances are the errors appearing? Are the errors appearing on the page you're viewing or showing up in the logs?